# Run function after 1sec from loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery's load() to load multiple images.

```
for(i = 1; i <img.length; i++){
   $('#dvA'+i).load('icon/im'+i+'.png');
   $('#bvB'+i).load('media/im'+i+'.png');
};
```

How do I do a setInterval when all the above are completed loading? So basically I need to fire `functionA()` after 1sec after all the images are loaded.

```
var isReady = setInterval(function() {
    functionA();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: where you are having your `for` loop placed?

Comment: You probably want to go with setTimeout() instead of setInterval() for this case.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao: Sorry, what do you mean where?

Comment: @JavaScript: Agreed. thanks. But how can I do know if all images are completed loading for the setTimeout() ?

Comment: I mean where both the codes located? inside same function/event or different?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Both are on the root. Same as shown in the question.

Comment: @Bekki: In Javascript you can use the onload() event on img tags and just set an attribute on complete and then select all missing ones by the missing attribute. I do not know in jQuery tho.

Comment: @JavaScript: thanks. :) Since I've done in Jquery I'll wait for an jquery answer.

Comment: No more answers can be provided as the question has been marked as duplicate!! Check the answer mentioned in the duplicate link!